# Somebody hacked my calculator

Tags: calculation-puzzle

Harvey the hacker struck again. After powering on my calculator, I entered the Keystrokes in the order shown below. Instead of the Expected Result, I got the Hacked Result.

What will be the last Hacked Result?

**Update / Hints:**

As mentioned in the comments, these are important observations:

- Rows 2 and 9 have the same Keystrokes, but different Hacked Results
- The Hacked Result is always bigger than the Expected Result

Once you know the answer, the Hacked Result can be calculated with simple math by doing this:

> Tapping your finger on the grid

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Keystrokes}&\textbf{Expected Result}&\textbf{Hacked Result} \\ \hline
2+4*2-3= & 7 & 16 \\ \hline
8/4+3-1= & 4 & 14 \\ \hline
2-6/3+8/4= & 2 & 15 \\ \hline
4*(2+2)= & 16 & 28 \\ \hline
7-(2-3)*3= & 10 & 25 \\ \hline
5+0/1+(5-3)= & 7 & 25 \\ \hline
6/3*3= & 6 & 19 \\ \hline
(5-3)*5-3= & 7 & 25 \\ \hline
8/4+3-1= & 4 & 21 \\ \hline
(3+7)/2= &  5& 23 \\ \hline
9-2*(3+1)= & 1 & ? \\ \hline
\end{array}

CSV version:

```
Keystrokes,Expected Result,Hacked Result
2+4*2-3=,7,16
8/4+3-1=,4,14
2-6/3+8/4=,2,15
4*(2+2)=,16,28
7-(2-3)*3=,10,25
5+0/1+(5-3)=,7,25
6/3*3=,6,19
(5-3)*5-3=,7,25
8/4+3-1=,4,21
(3+7)/2=,5,23
9-2*(3+1)=,1,?
```

Comment: How could 8/4+3-1 equals 14 or 21 in the example? (in row 2 & 9)

Comment: @Conifers "How could 8/4+3-1 equals 14 or 21 in the example? (in row 2 & 9)" That is an important observation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the answer is

> 22

Explanation

> result = expected result + number of symbols + number of the expression (row of the table)
>  so for the last expression is $1 + 10 + 11 = 22$

Comment: Impressive, well done ^.^

Answer (score 2):

I have maybe an answer, let me check.

> I think he changed the operator like here :

(3+7)/2 = 5 give

> (3*7)+2 = 23 as unexepected, so + become * and / become +

Taking another example : 8/4+3-1 = 4

> 8+4*3?1=21 so - become +

A last one to confirm : 5+0/1+(5-3)=7 become

> 5*0+1*(5+3) = 8

**And it didn't work.**
I will post my answer anyway in case it can help someone later.

Comment: Just checked programmatically: no operator replacements will solve the first line. It must be something else.

Comment: @Birjolaxew I also checked number replacements, but i didn't try both number and operators. I also thought about priority changes, but not working.

Comment: I think of something else, the hacked number are way bigger than regular result, maybe we should use this information in our calculation ?

Comment: @TinyDoowy "the hacked number are way bigger than regular result". That is an important observation.